# Can a creature immune to Immobilized walk away from a creature grabbing it?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, immobilized

**Grabbed:**

> While a creature is grabbed, it is immobilized. Maintaining this condition on the creature occupies whatever appendage, object, or effect the grabber used to initiate the grab. This condition ends immediately on the creature if the grabber is subjected to an effect that prevents it from taking actions, or if the creature ends up outside the range of the grabbing power or effect.

How does this interact with an ability that prevents the immobilized condition.  For example: the Battlemind's **Step of the Pursuer**:

> Hit: 1[W] + Constitution modifier damage. You are immune to the slowed and immobilized conditions until the end of your next turn.

This came up last night and my ruling at the table was Immobilized is one condition and Grabbed is another.  The power made the Battlemind immune to the Immobilized condition, but not Grabbed.  I continued to apply Grabbed 'as-is' and tabled the conversation.  She was stuck in my giant's grasp until escaped or otherwise freed.

Now I'm rethinking and wondering if I should've ruled it as such:

- Battlemind is still Grabbed for the purposes of what affects apply to
  grabbed individuals.  I.E. the grabber still does special grabby
  damange to her.
- The Battlemind is not Immobilized, which would allow
  her to saunter off at her next opportunity without the need to roll
  an escape check.

But I haven't totally convinced myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No, the Battlemind cannot walk away and is immobilized.**

The Rules Compendium, page 229:

> **No Degrees of Effect:**
>   Conditions don't have degrees of effect: either a creature has a condition or it doesn't

While the Battlemind is preventing the Immobilized condition, it is not preventing the Grabbed condition.  Since we can't split the Grabbed condition up and only apply part of it, the Battlemind must stay Immobilized as well.

Comment: I don't see how this rules out the idea that the creature is still Grabbed but the definition of Grabbed has changed. If a creature gets hit with a condition that is Blinded + 5 ongoing damage (save ends) and the creature is immune to Blinded, it still takes the 5 ongoing damage.

Comment: @Snowbody - to my knowledge there is no condition named "Blinded + 5 ongoing damage"  Those are two separate conditions.  You can tell because it is usually followed by "Save ends both"

Comment: I think I see what you're saying -- the battlemind is not immune to Grabbed, so the Grabbed condition is in effect. And I agree with that. The question is, do you draw a distinction between a condition and the effects of that condition. For instance, a condition is "Granting Combat Advantage to all attackers". One of the effects of that condition is that attackers get a +2 to attack. But there's a feat that negates that. If you have that feat, attackers don't get a +2 to attack any more, but you still grant CA. This doesn't violate the "No Degrees of Effect" rule. I think it's the same here.